# My sql query to get data between two particular dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table where column type "timesatmp" and I need to fetch data which are between two particular dates.

I tried with this its not working:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where column_name >= "2015-06-01 00:00:00" and column_name <= now();
```

Column name is of datatype "timestamp" and store value in terms of 2015-02-05 19:37:28 like that.

Comment: The column type is "timesatmp"?  Is this a typo?  Does your query use the correct column name?  Can you leave off the "and column_name<= now()" section?  I don't see what the benefit of the AND clause is.  Can you share the error message?

Comment: This just worked for me: `where column_name between '2015-06-16 00:00:00' and now()` with the timestamp literal encapsulated with either single or double quotes.

Comment: "it's not working" is a very vague description of the behavior you are observing. An error message being returned? No rows being returned? Too many rows being returned?

Comment: There is no issue in query it seems you are doing some typo...please check carefully

Comment: Those who have voted down the answers. Provide the comments why they down voted the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine (apart from the unfortunate identifiers `table_name` and `column_name`.

As a demonstration:

create and populate table:

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

 INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES 
  ('2015-02-05 19:37:28')
 ,('2015-06-01 00:00:00')
 ,('2015-06-02 02:02:02')
```

query:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM table_name 
  WHERE column_name >= "2015-06-01 00:00:00" 
    AND column_name <= NOW();
```

returns:

```
          column_name  
  -------------------
  2015-06-01 00:00:00
  2015-06-02 02:02:02
```

---

As I noted in a comment on your question:

"it's not working" is a very vague description of the behavior you are observing. An error message being returned? No rows being returned? Too many rows being returned?

Answer (score -1):

```
   select * from table_name where date(column_name) >= 'your_date' AND date(column_name) = now()
```

May be this will help to your question

Comment: How does this differ from OP query? What difference does this make. (I'm not saying there isn't a difference... I'm just saying that there's no indication why the OP would want to "try this", what problem does this solve?

Comment: i didn't get you. What you are trying to say?

Comment: I'm asking "*why*" OP should try this. What is the *problem* in the OP query will be *solved* by using this replacement query? (This answer makes it look like we are just throwing stuff at the wall to see if sticks. That is, we're throwing out solutions without having an understanding of the actual issue we are addressing.)

Comment: Ok. Then do u have any other solution for this? or do u have any ans for OP query why that query is working? @spencer7593

Answer (score -1):

You want to select the data between two particular dates then use two particular date values not the now() function as:

```
select * from table_name where column_name>= "2015-06-01 00:00:00" and column_name<= "2015-06-10 23:23:23";
```

OR

```
select * from table_name where column_name between "2015-06-01 00:00:00" and  "2015-06-10 23:23:23";
```

And if you want to select data from any particular date to till now then use your query as it is:

```
select * from table_name where column_name>= "2015-06-01 00:00:00" and column_name<= now();
```

OR

```
select * from table_name where column_name btween "2015-06-01 00:00:00" and  now();
```